# How to create a bootable, persistent Linux OS that doesn't lock up?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, live-usb

I'm trying to create a bootable, persistent Linux OS that I can run off a USB flash drive but I'm having no luck. I made a bootable Mint USB with no problem, and I booted into it. Seemed flawless up to that point. I worked for maybe a minute in the OS, connected to a wireless network, opened a folder, etc., and then the mouse just froze. And then the keyboard too. I rebooted and got the same behavior. After lots of googling, I couldn't find an answer so I decided to try a different OS.

I went through the same procedure with Ubuntu and eventually booted into the OS and had the same problem. Seemed to work fine for a minute or so and then it just froze. I tried different USB ports for the mouse, unplugging/replugging, but nothing worked.

Maybe it was a dumb idea to try Ubuntu, since I believe Mint is based on Ubuntu, but I'm looking for an OS that is solid, stable, and relatively user-friendly. (I have some Linux experience but am by no means an expert.)

Can anyone suggest ways I might try to realize my goal of having a bootable and persistent Linux environment on USB? Has anyone experienced this lockup problem before? Or maybe you have a recommendation for a different distro I should try that would be comparable to Mint/Ubuntu in terms of ease/usability (but not bloated).

I'm using a Dell XPS 15 9560 and a brand new SanDisk Cruzer 64GB flash drive. Thanks.

Comment: Install Ubuntu/Mint and immediately after reboot open terminal and install recommended proprietary drivers: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and reboot.

Comment: @Bob, I got a message that said "No drivers found for automatic installation"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely not the distribution (after all they all use more or less the same kernels and drivers) but there are several things to check, see here:

- for Ubuntu: https://github.com/rcasero/doc/wiki/Ubuntu-linux-on-Dell-XPS-15-(9560)
- for ArchLinux: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_15_9560

You will note that they have many things in common.

Answer (score -2):

I found that kali has the most stable and persistent Linux setup.

http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-live-usb-install

http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence

if you want Ubuntu I put my Ubuntu usb links on a pastbin since this username I am using has a reputation under 10:
https://pastebin.com/a92jJVhi

also check askubuntu.com - search persistence and persistent usb drive ...pretty sure there is a post that walks thru making a kali usb but it does not say kali....

Comment: totally confused by two down votes - answered question, and extensive experience with debian, ubuntu, and kali persistent drives will show differences in stability, critical default programs (so less is disrupted by new installs), and setup (grub, boot menu setups, iso customization methods and a ton persistent usb creation differences. (see ubuntu links...)  Dont want to post useful info if it is frowned upon here now....

Comment: @johnnyb1970 - persistent usb's are not favored - i love them but most forums dont have much in the way of resources to get them working.  Installing a linux os on a usb is the officially supported method you will find more support available for.  if you want stability in a persis. usb - try kali - its not  the most user friendly but it sticks to true debian pretty closely so its solid unix system.